# Regular Expression to exclude a particular filename in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have filename as `Day=17_$folder$`,trying to exclude this particular file given in a regular expression  in Java.

I have tried `[^Day=17_$folder$]`

Comment: can you provide some clear example?

Comment: To match this exact filename, you may use `^Day=17_\$folder\$$` (possibly with a `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag). Now, to _exclude_ it, the easier way is to use the same pattern and only proceed if there is _no match_.

Comment: Side remark: `[...]` is about matching a single character only.

Comment: Can `Day=17_$folder$` really be a filename ? It looks like variable assignment. If it is an exact literal, shouldn't a simple `str != 'Day=17_$folder$`` work ?